# resize LotusScript range

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

Using Lotus 123 for Windows 1997 (Yes very old)

I'm trying to do what in Excel VBA is a very simple thing; Offset and resize. But I'm stuck in LotusScript.

```
'this works fine in Excel
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set rg = ws.Range("MyRange").Offset(0, 1)
Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count, rg.Columns.Count - 1)

'how to complete this in LotusScript?
Dim DocLotus As Lotus123.Document
Set DocLotus ...
Dim rg As Lotus123.Range
Set rg = DocLotus.Ranges("MyRange")

'offset one column to the right

'resize one column less
```

Can you help me? I'm reading the help files but I can't find the right methods to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way to duplicate the Excel resize method although not exactly. This doesn't go beyond the end of SrcRange but that that was fine for my requirements.

```
Function Resize(SrcRange As Range, ByVal RowCount As Integer, ByVal ColumnCount As Integer) As Range

    'this function resizes the range but cannot go beyond the end of SrcRange
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim EndCell As Range
    Set StartCell = SrcRange.cell(0, 0)
    Set EndCell = SrcRange.cell(RowCount - 1, ColumnCount - 1)

    Dim LeftAddr As String
    Dim RightAddr As String
    LeftAddr = Left(StartCell.CoordinateString, InStr(StartCell.CoordinateString, "..") + 1)
    RightAddr = Left(EndCell.CoordinateString, InStr(EndCell.CoordinateString, "..") - 1)

    Dim NewRange As Range
    Set NewRange = SrcRange.Parent.Ranges(LeftAddr & RightAddr)
    Set Resize = NewRange

End Function
```

Here is the OffSet method, but again it doesn't go beyond the end of SrcRange

```
Function OffSet(SrcRange As Range, ByVal byRow As Integer, ByVal byColumn As Integer) As Range

    'this function offsets the beginning of the range but does not go beyond the end of SrcRange
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim EndCell As Range
    Set StartCell = SrcRange.Cell(byRow, byColumn)
    Set EndCell = SrcRange.Cell(SrcRange.EndRow - SrcRange.StartRow, SrcRange.EndColumn - SrcRange.StartColumn)

    Dim LeftAddr As String
    Dim RightAddr As String
    LeftAddr = Left(StartCell.CoordinateString, InStr(StartCell.CoordinateString, "..") + 1)
    RightAddr = Left(EndCell.CoordinateString, InStr(EndCell.CoordinateString, "..") - 1)

    Dim NewRange As Range
    Set NewRange = SrcRange.Parent.Ranges(LeftAddr & RightAddr)
    Set OffSet = NewRange

End Function
```

To extend these to function exactly like Excel, I think I would need a Cells function like this; but again this is incomplete as it only works for the first sheet.

```
Function Cells(RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long)
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = CurrentDocument.Ranges("A:A1..A:IV8192")
    Set rg = rg.Cell(RowNum - 1, ColNum - 1)
    Set Cells = rg
End Function
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, but I think searching the forum of lotus 123 will be helpful (yes the forum is still there)

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ssforum.nsf/SortedAllThreadedweb?OpenView&ExpandView&RestricttoCategory=1-2-3

maybe you are after this:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ssforum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/83d603bad276a3e185256cb5001110d7?OpenDocument

Comment: Thanks for the info about the forum. I didn't know about it. That will be helpful. Also the second link was helpful.

Comment: Your links no longer work. Do you know if they moved the Lotus forum or is it completely gone?